# Performance of bytearray and alternatives

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures

I am writing a parser for a protocol working over TCP.

Some messages are split between multiple packets so I need to be able to "peek" into my stream with a possibility of going back and also to append incoming data at the end. On the other hand, I would like to be able to discard the content of the packets I have successfully parsed.

- The problem with `bytes` is that appending requires copying (not in CPython, but then it is also impossible to delete the first bytes in an immutable object).
- The problem with `bytearray` is that flushing the already seen bytes also requires copying (or so I thought, see below)
- The problem with `collections.deque` is the huge memory requirement. Same with `list`.

However, I did some tests with `bytearray` and it seems the pop(0) operation is far more efficient than with lists:

```
from time import time

n = 100000

for container in [bytearray, list]:
    print(container)

    a = container(b'a'*n)
    t = time()
    for i in range(n):
        del a[0]
    print('del a[0]', time() - t)

    a = container(b'a'*n)
    t = time()
    for i in range(n):
        del a[-1]
    print('del a[-1]', time() - t)

    a = container(b'a'*n)
    t = time()
    for i in range(n-1):
        del a[1]
    print('del a[1]', time() - t)

    a = container(b'a'*n)
    t = time()
    for i in range(n-1):
        del a[-2]
    print('del a[-2]', time() - t)

    print()
```

It seems that `del a[0]` and `del a[-1]` have about the same complexity for `bytearray`, in cpython2, cpython3 and pypy3.

I would like to know:

1. How is that possible? Is there a more efficient way than `del a[:k]` to delete the first `k` bytes?
2. Is there a more efficient data structure than the `bytearray`? (maybe using `array`, `memoryview` or `ctypes`)

Comment: depending on how you want to use it a memoryview wrapping a bytearray, or even another memoryview, can be a very efficient way of working with bytearray slices. No need to delete anything.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I need to delete old bytes because I can receive a big number of messages. If I don't delete them, I will literally have a StackOverflow ;)

Comment: Well, one efficient way to accomplish this is with a buffer pool. As you finish with a "buffer" (really just a `bytearray`) you return it to the pool. A small class can effectively manage a buffer pool.

Comment: @James K Polk do you think it is more efficient than just bytearray? Maybe a deque of ctypes.c_char_Array_4096?

Comment: I think I get the idea, it's like grouping the memory allocation and freeing into chunks.

Comment: It all depends on the pattern of usage, how often new buffers are needed versus how often old buffers are discarded. Some applications only need one buffer, not really much of a pool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python deliberately sacrifices code performance for programmer's performance.

Use whatever is the most convenient to use.

*When* you have a correctly working implementation *and* the performance proves to be inadequate, replace *critical bits only* (as shown by profiling) with faster equivalents. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Overview:_Optimize_what_needs_optimizing for more info.

---

That said, a prime candidate *for the use case you described* would be a "chunked buffer" that would return slices transparently from a series of buffers.

Extracting data from it will still require copying (since all standard Python types own their memory), and you'll have interpreter overhead if you implement the type in pure Python. So to get any significant improvement, you're likely to have to go into Cython/C or something. That's why it's so important to get the general design right first -- in pure Python, it's much easier to change things.

Comment: In fact, I would be happy if someone could explain how Python achieve this performance of bytearray

Comment: @Labo `bytearray` is implemented in C, that's how. It's a thin wrapper over `char[]`. Even if copying is involved, `memcpy`ing a chunk of a 100kB array is like instant.

Comment: @Labo you can always check the implementation in the official source repo @ https://github.com/python/cpython if you're interested in details. `bytearray` is at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/bytearrayobject.c .